# Проблема с загрузкой анимации

Tags: javascript, php

Есть страница с формами. На первой форме пользователь отправляет запись в БД после чего нажимает на форму отправки, далее я запускаю анимацию перехода ко второй форме, но анимация не запускается. В консоли появляется примечание: "Элемент не имеет атрибута автозаполнения". Уже вставлял `autocomplete="on"` во все `input`. Помогите.

```html
<?php
session_start();
error_reporting(E_ALL);
include('config.php');

if (isset($_SESSION['user'])) {
    $user = $_SESSION['user'];

    // TOTAL
    $sql = "SELECT SUM(products.price) as total FROM cart INNER JOIN products ON products.id = cart.productid WHERE cart.user=:user";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $total = $query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    $sql="SELECT MAX(id) + 1 AS ordid FROM orders;";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->execute();
    $ordid=$query->fetch(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);

    // FECTH PRODUCTS
    $sql = "SELECT cart.id,products.title,products.price,products.img FROM cart INNER JOIN products ON products.id = cart.productid WHERE cart.user=:user";
    $query = $db->prepare($sql);
    $query->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
    $query->execute();
    $results = $query->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_OBJ);


    //INSERT ORDER
    if (isset($_POST['orderplace'])) {
        $address = $_POST['address'];
        $sql = "INSERT INTO orders(user, address) VALUES(:user,:address)";
        $query = $db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->bindParam(':address', $address, PDO::PARAM_STR);
        $query->execute();
        $lastInsertId = $db->lastInsertId();
        if ($lastInsertId) {

            foreach ($results as $item) {
                $sqlitem = "INSERT INTO orderitems (oid,ptitle,price) VALUES (:orderid,:title,:price)";
                $stmtitem = $db->prepare($sqlitem);
                $stmtitem->bindParam("orderid", $lastInsertId, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmtitem->bindParam("title", $item->title, PDO::PARAM_STR);
                $stmtitem->bindParam("price", $item->price, PDO::PARAM_INT);
                $stmtitem->execute();
            }

            //CLEAR CART
            $sql = "DELETE FROM cart WHERE user = (:user)";
            $query = $db->prepare($sql);
            $query->bindParam(':user', $user, PDO::PARAM_STR);
            $query->execute();
            //echo "<script>alert('Order Placed')</script>";  
              
        } else{
            echo"<script>alert('Error!')</script>";
        }
        }
    }


?>


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css/chkout.css">
    <title>Document</title>
</head>
<body>
<div class="container">
        <form  method="post" name="ordplc" id="orddet">
            <!-- <h2>Оформление Заказа</h2> -->
            <div class="ord-detail">
                <h2>Оформление Заказа</h2>
                <h3 class="details">Total :₽ <?php echo $total->total; ?></h3>
                <h3 class="details">Номер Заказа:<?php echo $ordid -> ordid;?></h3>
            </div>
            <div class="adr">
                <input name="address" type="text" class="form-control mb-4" placeholder="Адрес доставки">
            </div>
            <div class="box-btn">
                <input class="btn ord-place-btn" id="transit" type="submit" value="Оформить" name="orderplace">
            </div>
        </form>
            <div class='payment-section'>
                <form method='POST' name='payment-form' id="pmt" action='https://yoomoney.ru/quickpay/confirm'> 
                    <h2>Оплата</h2>
                    <input type='hidden' name='receiver' value='****************'/>
                    <input type='hidden' name='quickpay-form' value='button'/>
                    <input type='text' name='sum' value='<?php echo $total->total; ?>' data-type='number'/>
                    <input class='btn payment-btn' type='submit' value='Оплатить' name='paymnt_btn'>
                </form>
            </div>
            <div class="step-row">
                <div class="div" id="progress"></div>
                <div class="step-col"><small>Оформление</small></div>
                <div class="step-col"><small>Оплата</small></div>
            </div>
    </div>

    <script>
        var ordform = document.getElementById("orddet");
        var paymentform = document.getElementById("pmt");

        var transition = document.getElementById("transit");

        transition.onclick = function(){
            ordform.style.left = "-450px";
            paymentform.style.left = "40px";
        }
    </script>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: [как задать хороший вопрос](//ru.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask)

Comment: <style>#transit{transition: 2s;}</style>
ordform.style.transform = "translate(-450px, 0px)";